# c# serialize xml custom attributes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, attributes

When I serialize class object into xml. Properties get saved but not their Attributes. Is there any way we can serialize/de-serialize their attributes as well

Following is example:

```
[Category("Invoice Fare(Selling Price) / Client Fare PP")]
        [Description("Client Tax / Tax PP")]
        [DisplayName("Client Tax / Tax PP")]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [RadSortOrder(5)]
        public string clientTax { get; set; }
```

like above example could be like below

```
<clientTax Category='xxx' Description='aaa'></clientTax>
```

Comment: Attributes are per class, not per object. If you deserialize to the same class, you get the same attributes. If you deserialize to the other class, you won't get attributes of the original class anyway.

Comment: what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: No. That is not a supported usage; not least: there would be no way to deserialize into them, since attributes are baked into the IL at build time.

Comment: i m thinking to write my own xml serializer.. not sure where to start..

Comment: i'd create a layer of indirection that `clientTax` has those properties.

Answer (score -1):

To serialize to XML attributes, you will need to make a class where properties will be the XML attributes decorated with the `[XmlAttribute]` annotation.

To reproduce your exemple, it would look like this :

```
public class ClientTax
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```